# How is Steve McGarett of "Five-O" able to be a civilian police officer if he is in the military as well?

Tags: hawaii-five-0

How is Steve McGarett of "Five-O" able to be a civilian police officer if he is in the military as well?  Is it possible in real life to be in the military but assigned as a civilian police officer?

Answer (score 4):

Commander Steven J. McGarrett is a member of the **USNR** ([United States Navy Reserves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Navy_Reserve)).

Members of the Naval Reserve traditionally give over just one weekend per month for drilling and two weeks per annum for their annual training. As such, a member of the USNR would need another job (such as working as a policeman) in order to support themselves financially.

A few seconds on google reveals that combining police work with joining a military Reserve service (or, more commonly, leaving military active service and becoming a Reservist and *then* joining the police) is actually a pretty common career choice for real world Naval Reservists like [Police Detective Navy Chief Lorelei Tanney, USNR](http://www.themilitaryview.com/?q=node/191)

Comment: I agree with the poster above, but they refer to McGarrett as Commander. So, in real life, do policemen during their NON-Reserve duty still maintain the title "Commander" in their civilian employment. I would think that during the off period, Commander would be inappropriate to use as a title in the Civilian law enforcement job. Maybe I am wrong, but would be good to know any other Police officers in McGarett's situation who still are called by their military rank while working in their civilian military job.

Comment: @curlyq - I don't know about the US, but in the UK it would be both normal and [appropriate](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/professions/armed-forces/army/retired-and-former-officers) to refer to a Reserve officer that senior by their military rank in civilian life.

Comment: Maybe his rank in the police force is commander?

Comment: @jamesmcleod - I'm reasonably sure he's a Detective in the police force, not a Commander.